# My custom UITableViewCell table cell shows up as a blank list of items

Tags: ios, objective-c, nib

Basically I have a custom UITableViewCell which I made in my nib file. Within that I have some labels and whatnot that I want to be able to edit programatically. I called my nib file "post" and I made its file owner "post" and I set its class to "post" under file owner as well. I linked all my labels within my nib to this class:

post.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface post : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *authorComments;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *time;

@end
```

post.m:

```
#import "post.h"

@implementation post

    @synthesize title = _title;
    @synthesize authorComments = _authorComments;
    @synthesize time = _time;

@end
```

An image of my nib file:

[image]

So now everything in my nib file is linked with my post class *except* for the actual cell itself because I was told I had to link that with a "view" but I'm not sure how (I tried linking it to backgroundView but this did not fix my problem). I've also tried giving the actual cell object the class post but it does not fix my problem.

Then in my controller I have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // this is the identifier that I gave the table cell within my nib
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"post";

    // grabs me a cell to use
    post *cell = (post *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[post alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // sets the text on one of the labels within my cell to something else
    cell.title.text = @"this is a test";

    // returns my customized cell
    return cell;

}
```

However when I run my app I just get this:

[image]

I know that the problem I'm having has to do with my custom cell, because I had it working previously, when I set the file owner on my nib to my controller, instead of attempting what I'm doing now which is trying to make a subclass of UITableViewCell. All I want to do is to be able to create a custom cell with multiple different labels on it, and then be able to edit the text on the cell programatically.

If it helps, here are all my source files and my nib file:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7822837/source.zip

Comment: You did not give refrence outlets with your controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do two things

**In xib file**

DisConnect all outlets of file owner and connect the outlets to your custom cell object

[image]

**In code**

Load the cell from nib

```
if (cell == nil) {

    //cell = [[post alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"post" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! What was the difference between making conections between file owner and the cell?

Comment: Coooolll... Thanks a lot ...I was doing the same mistake...connecting from file's owner.

Answer (score 10):

You have to registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: in your UITableView, something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"post" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"post"];
}
```

**Swift:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "post", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "post")
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that was my problem, but I should probably override that method in my custom class anyway to make sure my TableView reuses cells. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this code is not correct, as you are trying to pass a NSString in the place of a UINib.

The correct code is: 

[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"post" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"post"];

Comment: After spending 2 days searching around with the same problem, this line of code fixed it. Thank you. I don't understand why it was absent in all examples I read ?

Answer (score 0):

Give the referencing Outlet to your `ViewController`, You didn't given a referencing outlet to your `ViewController`.

Comment: Do you mean I should make an IBOutlet on my controller and connect that right to my cell? That works, but then I can't edit the multiple labels I added to my cell because I have nothing to connect them to.